# Connect Bluetooth devices without user interaction in Android programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

How to connect Bluetooth devices without user interaction for pairing and connect via secure method too? And also want to know about android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEDGE permission.

Comment: As per documentation(android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEDGE ), Allows applications to pair bluetooth devices without user interaction, and to allow or disallow phonebook access or message access. This is not available to third party applications.

Comment: @FebiMathew can you please explain me in detail. i did not get what you are trying to say.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED

Comment: okey fine Thanks @FebiMathew. but can you help me to solve this error that i pasted below. 
 java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10633 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.

Comment: Can we see what code you have at present, and what you are actually stuck on? This is rather broad and vague at present.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is use the `BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED` permission, but you can't use this permission if your app is a third party app (non-system app). To learn more, see Android API: [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED)